# Excel get multiples values based on a match condition?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 1000s of records.
The columns look like this:

```
> Path            Year-Month    Timestamp         # SN  Filename                Match
> D:\ABC\trt21.mrk  2012-04     4/17/2012 10:57      2  trt21.mrk              abcd.mrk
> D:\DEF\pty09.mrk  2012-05     5/17/2012 10:57      1  pty09.mrk              zzz12.mrk
> D:\ABC\abcd.mrk   2012-06     6/17/2012 10:55      1  abcd.mrk               ddy1.mrk
> D:\ABC\abcd.mrk   2012-07    7/2/2012 10:34        3  abcd.mrk
```

The columns Path, year-Month, Timestamp, #SN are all the related information for the column Filename. Match column contains some files that I m interested in. I want to be able to find if filename in Match column is in Filename column, then give me its all related info such as Path, Year-Month, Timestamp, #SN, Filename.

So it will bring me back this:

```
> Path            Year-Month    Timestamp         # SN  Filename                Match

> D:\ABC\abcd.mrk   2012-06     6/17/2012 10:55      1  abcd.mrk               abcd.mrk
> D:\ABC\abcd.mrk   2012-07    7/2/2012 10:34        3  abcd.mrk
```

Any idea on how to get it? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

in your specific case it would be something like this: `=VLOOKUP(A1,A1:D25,1,FALSE)`

A1 would be the value you are looking up, A1:D25 would be your data source (table that has the source data), 1 is the column number that you would like to return in relation to your source data

Comment: using vlookup is fine but I need to compare if and only if Match column has a filename in Filename column, then only give me all the records related to that Match in Filename. Any idea how?

Comment: that is what the vlookup does, if there's a match then it will return the records related to it

Comment: I have this function on G2=VLOOKUP(F2,A2:E4,1,FALSE) and it returned me N/A

Comment: send me your worksheet classical enthusiast gmail (no spaces)

Comment: my original spreadhseet is huge. Can we play on my example?(above)? TIA.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13478/discussion-between---and-nemo)

Answer (score -1):

Is using the Sort and Filter not an option? Using sort and filter, if you highlight all of your data, then from the Data Ribbon select filter, it will allow you to highlight what data you want to view based on that column. So if you'd like to see just the files that have "abcd.mrk", you can hit the dropdown on the Filename column, and only put the checkmark next to "abcd.mrk". If you want to view multiple matches, such as "abcd.mrk" and "pty09.mrk", you would just put checkboxes next to both of those in the dropdown list.

Comment: it would be better if I had few records. I have 90+ thousands of records. In the end I want a list of them fulfilling my criteria. Any solution? TIA.